# How to display the daily view only from 9am to 6pm using tui calendar?

Tags: javascript, tui-calendar

i am using tui calendar https://ui.toast.com/tui-calendar and i want to display the daily view only from 9am to 6pm in calender but i have no idea how can i do that please help me thank u.

[image]

**script**

```
var Calendar = tui.Calendar;
var calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', {



   week: {
       hourStart: 9,
       hourEnd: 18
   }

      defaultView: 'week',
      taskView: false,
      useCreationPopup: false,
      useDetailPopup: true,
      allDaySlot: false,
      droppable: false,
      template: {
        monthDayname: function(dayname) {
          return '<span class="calendar-week-dayname-name">' + dayname.label + '</span>';
        }
      }
    });

    document.getElementById('my-today-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
      calendar.today();

    });
    document.getElementById('my-next-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
      calendar.next();
    });
    document.getElementById('my-prev-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
      calendar.prev();
    });
    document.getElementById('weekView').addEventListener('click', function() {
      calendar.changeView('week', true);
    });
    document.getElementById('monthView').addEventListener('click', function() {
      calendar.changeView('month', true);
    });
```